# Current-item (active) highlighting does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I had current item highlighting work like a charm when my page url were marked as #.
  When I created actual php files to other static pages and changed the links inside a href, highlighting does not work anymore. What should I do?

html:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTLEHT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="naviwrap"><?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="content"></div>

<div class"footer"><?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?></div>


<script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

included menu.php file:

```
<nav class="menu">
       <ul class="clearfix">
          <li id="linkone" class="jlist" data-linkid="link1"><a href="index.php">Avaleht</a></li>
          <li id="linktwo" class="jlist" class="current-item" data-linkid="link2"><a href="meist.php">Meist</a></li>
          <li id="linkthree" class="jlist" data-linkid="ink3"><a href="tooted.php">Tooted</a></li>
          <li id="linkfour" class="jlist" data-linkid="link4"><a href="galerii.php">Galerii</a></li>
          <li id="linkfive" class="jlist" data-linkid="link5"><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>

       </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin-top: 3.2%;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Khmer UI;
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.30s;
  color: #ABABAB;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

.menu li:active > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    color: red;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 105%;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  color: #282828;
}
```

And finally jquery code which worked before I changed a href links in html:

```
$(function(){

  $('.jlist').click(function() {

    $('.jlist').removeClass('current-item');

    $(this).addClass('current-item');     

  });

});
```

Comment: Your jQuery code id working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/YSYpw/58/

Comment: @RinoRaj won't work when new page loads

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will be that the new page will load when links are clicked and scripts will run all over again.

You can set the class in php since you know which controller is loading there

Comment: Can create a variable name that is the same in each controller. Then in the html `<li class="<?= $controller == 'kontakt' ? 'jlist current':'jList'?>">`

Comment: Or another way is pass a variable to javascript that would match an attribute in each element and have javascript set the class by matching. This can be done by parsing the url in javascript but is clumsy for home page because might be just domain or index.php